# unable to cancel schedule task

Tags: android

hello i am using java.util.Timer for scheduling task and show notification for appointments only one time but if i cancel schedule appointment with help of timer.cancel(); and timer.purge();
it's unable to cancel and it performs on a particular time...

Please Help....

Comment: Please post the relevant sections of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Timer` for scheduling an apointment, or another thing what can happen while your activity is not in foreground it is better to use `AlarmManager`.

Task scheduled with `Timer` can not being runned exactly in scheduled time.